# R - Check and count repetitive substrings and generate a simplified string [Value (repetitions)]

Tags: r, list, google-analytics-api, strsplit

I am using the library RGA to get some Google Analytics' Multi-Channel Funnel reports. One of the dimensions represents the user's channel path, taking traffic source into consideration. If User A, f.i., visited our site 7 times the last month, channel.path shows something like that:

> Organic Search > Direct > Direct > Referral > Direct > Direct > Direct

I am trying to simplify this output to show something like this,

> Organic Search > Direct (x2) > Referral > Direct (x3)

which is easier to read and simulates how Google shows channel.path in its frontend. As user's sessions increases, this output is even more necessary, because there are channel.paths with more than 30 direct consecutive sessions (f. e. someone that visits our site every day to read the news) that can be simplified by a unique Direct (x30).

I assume, that the first step is to create a list of substrings from every channel.path:

```
# Create 3 dummy strings that emulate possible channel.path
arr <- c("Organic Search > Direct > Direct", "Direct > Direct > Direct", "Referral")

# Split the dummy strings into substrings
arrSubStrings <- strsplit(arr, " > ")
```

Which generates the following list:

```
> arrSubStrings
[[1]]
[1] "Organic Search" "Direct"         "Direct"        

[[2]]
[1] "Direct" "Direct" "Direct"

[[3]]
[1] "Referral"
```

And from here to compare each substring with the anterior substring to check for repetition, store the "counter" in between the substrings and use paste to join again every substring in a single string. Do you know of any package or function that I should use for achieving something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a little complex, but the logic is pretty straightforward. It uses `rle` in "data.table", after using `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package. I've also loaded "dplyr" to make chaining the steps a little easier on the eyes:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)

data.table(ID = 1:length(arr), arr = arr) %>% ## create a data.table of arr
  cSplit("arr", ">", "long") %>%              ## Split into a long form
  .[, rle(as.character(arr)), by = .(ID)] %>% ## Calculate the run lengths
  .[, paste(values,                           ## Paste values and lengths
            sprintf(" (x%s)", lengths),       ## ... after formatting lengths
            collapse = " > ", sep = ""),      ## ... collapsed by >
    by = .(ID)] %>%                           ## ... and grouped by ID
  .[, gsub(" (x1)", "", V1, fixed = TRUE)]    ## Remove the (x1) values
# [1] "Organic Search > Direct (x2)"                         
# [2] "Direct (x3)"                                          
# [3] "Referral"                                        
# [4] "Organic Search > Direct (x2) > Referral > Direct (x3)"
# [5] "Organic Search (x2) > Direct > Organic Search (x2)"
```

---

Here's the same concept, but done using base R:

```
arrSplit <- strsplit(arr, " > ", TRUE)
sapply(arrSplit, function(x) {
  A <- rle(x)
  A$lengths <- sprintf("(x%s)", A$lengths)
  temp <- paste(A$values, A$lengths, collapse = " > ", sep = " ")
  gsub(" (x1)", "", temp, fixed = TRUE)
})
# [1] "Organic Search > Direct (x2)"                         
# [2] "Direct (x3)"                                          
# [3] "Referral"                                             
# [4] "Organic Search > Direct (x2) > Referral > Direct (x3)"
# [5] "Organic Search (x2) > Direct > Organic Search (x2)"
```

***Sample data:***

```
arr <- c("Organic Search > Direct > Direct", 
         "Direct > Direct > Direct", 
         "Referral", 
         "Organic Search > Direct > Direct > Referral > Direct > Direct > Direct", 
         "Organic Search > Organic Search > Direct > Organic Search > Organic Search")
arr
# [1] "Organic Search > Direct > Direct"                                          
# [2] "Direct > Direct > Direct"                                                  
# [3] "Referral"                                                                  
# [4] "Organic Search > Direct > Direct > Referral > Direct > Direct > Direct"    
# [5] "Organic Search > Organic Search > Direct > Organic Search > Organic Search"
```

Comment: Really clean and understandable solutions. I get arr from data.frame as `arr <- ga.mcf[, "channelPath"]`, although for your second method I have to adapt your code as `arrSplit <- strsplit(as.character(arr), " > ", TRUE)` for it to work. I chosed the splitstackshape option because it seems to produce a faster result with my code, as I have to make the process for more than 100 different sites (however, this is a totally subjective judging because I have to call the api everytime). But anyway, really good logic!